# Pandas, ParserError: Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tokenize

I'm studying the book "Python for Data Analysis (written by Wes McKinney)."

While working on CH10, I had a problem.

The code below is what I wrote in Google Colab.

```
!wget https://github.com/wesm/pydata-book/blob/2nd-edition/examples/stock_px_2.csv

close_px = pd.read_csv('stock_px_2.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

close_px.head()
```

Then I got this error.

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 107, saw 2
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: try using the link `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/examples/stock_px_2.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the raw CSV file, I can read the values:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wesm/pydata-book/2nd-edition/examples/stock_px_2.csv"
close_px = pd.read_csv(csv_url, parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
print(close_px.head())
```

Output:

```
            AAPL   MSFT    XOM     SPX
2003-01-02  7.40  21.11  29.22  909.03
2003-01-03  7.45  21.14  29.24  908.59
2003-01-06  7.45  21.52  29.96  929.01
2003-01-07  7.43  21.93  28.95  922.93
2003-01-08  7.28  21.31  28.83  909.93
```